# PDF: insert a line of text into an existing PDF file

Tags: php, bash, pdf

I have a PDF file and I wish to add on the footer of all pages (except the first two) a line of plain text (not a logo or something alike).

Did anyone has an example of how this can be done (in any language)?

**Update:**
The original PDF was made with Scribus and I have total control of it. So if it easier to make a find&replace operation, that's fine too.

Comment: Modifying a pdf is non-trivial, especially if the text is actually rendered as an image and not embedded as a text+font+layout sequence.

Comment: I updated the question above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If "the footer" is defined by a position (i.e. specified in millimeters for example), you can just use your favorite language ([TeX](http://miktex.org/), [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php), [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/), [Postscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/), ...) to render a PDF containing the two lines and then overlay this PDF on top of your existing PDF using *[pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)*.

If you want to apply the overlay only to the first two pages, you have to use a temporary file like this:

```
pdftk input.pdf stamp overlay.pdf output temp.pdf
pdftk A=input.pdf B=temp.pdf cat A1-2 B3-end output result.pdf
```

Comment: Sorry, I ment pages. thank you for the tip, I'll try and post the results.

Comment: All I want is to insert plain text (not a logo or something alike). I guess I'd have to substitute the "stamp overlay.pdf" for another command. Would you know what it is?

Comment: No, you have to create a PDF to overlay it. Think of a PDF as an image: You have to render the text first. Should be quite simple with the tools I named.

Comment: So in overlay.pdf, I'd have the text I want to insert, is it?

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64385770/6723250

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Scribus file you can use masterpages.

http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Working_with_Master_Pages