# How to find and replace text in a existing PDF file with PDFTK (or other command line application)

Tags: bash, pdf, pdftk

I have on each page of my PDF document a line with this string:

`%REPLACE%`

Which I'd like to find and replace with another string.

Does anyone know how to do this with some command line application such as PDFTK?

This [folk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746687/pdf-insert-a-line-of-text-into-an-existing-pdf-file) gave me an important clue however I'd like something more direct.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to program a text search and replace in PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220445/how-to-program-a-text-search-and-replace-in-pdf-files)

Comment: I added an answer to the above question of a custom program I wrote for this purpose https://stackoverflow.com/a/67932076/32453

Answer (score 52):

You can try to modify content of your PDF as follows

1. Uncompress the text streams of PDF

   ```
   pdftk file.pdf output uncompressed.pdf uncompress
   ```
2. Use **sed** to replace your text with another

   ```
   sed -e "s/ORIGINALSTRING/NEWSTRING/g" <uncompressed.pdf >modified.pdf
   ```
3. If this attempt was successful, re-compress the PDF with **pdftk**

   ```
   pdftk modified.pdf output recompressed.pdf compress
   ```

***Note:** This way is not successful every time*, mainly due to font subsetting

Comment: I can't make this work with the PDF file exported from Google Docs (even when I choose arial as the only font). I am afraid that I'd have to use some other application only to write the page and then try the very simple and wonderful code you wrote...

Comment: with *pdfedit* you can have more chances (if fonts are fully embedded) to edit text content - http://pdfedit.cz/en/index.html

Comment: pdfedit can be used also from command line without gui (see its site for command line utilities)

Comment: Note that this will only work when the text is using `Tj` command in PDF along with plain ASCII chars. As soon as octal, hex or glyph refences are used, you are lost.

Comment: For anyone with Mac M1 this might be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859527/how-to-solve-pdftk-bad-cpu-type-in-executable-on-mac

Comment: I had to replace `sed`, because of encoding issues, with `perl -pi.bak -e 's/findthis/replacewiththis/g' uncompressed.pdf` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6995010/241542

Comment: Is this able to use regex for `sed`? 
Without regex, it works. 
But with regex it says ```
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file:
   modified.pdf
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

Comment: I suspect pdfbox has something available what would help with the font subsetting.  I have an example to start working with: Forked from https://gist.github.com/DavidYKay/82f20ba67c50c499ebb3 from
 * https://jackson-brain.com/using-pdfbox-to-locate-text-coordinates-within-a-pdf-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

For making a small change just on a few pages, `inkscape` can do a good job. It can also fix some issues in diagrams and with table borders. One must process each page separately, though, and stick the pages back together using `pdfunite`. (Unchanged page ranges can be extracted with `pdfseparate`.)

Inspiration:
https://tatica.org/2015/07/13/edit-pdf-inkscape/

Comment: For simple changes, this works with Inkscape. Inkscape 1.2 (released on 2022-02-05) supports multi-page PDF documents for both import and export, so it is no longer needed to use `pdfunite`. To be able to edit the text, one first needs to do an Ungroup on the object that consists of a full PDF page.

Comment: "Inkscape encountered an internal error and will close now"

Answer (score 0):

[`changepagestring`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CAM-PDF/bin/changepagestring.pl) will do this in a single step, as easy as:

`changepagestring -o -v infile.pdf search-regex replace-str outfile.pdf`

However like the currently accepted answer, this is hit or miss and doesn't work as expected with all files.

Comment: Yes sadly this didn't work with my file, it could find 2 letters but not the whole word I wanted to find

Comment: I've been finding that when this fails, it's often just a matter of finding the right regex. I haven't figured out if there's a way to see the text exactly as needed to understand how it works, but a regex like 'word1*word2' may work where 'word1 word2' fails.

Comment: In Debian/unstable, `changepagestring` does not work at all (I've tried on a single word, so this is simpler than a regexp), even on a simple PDF file obtained with `pdflatex`, for which `pdftotext` can find the word. [Debian bug 1019979](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1019979).

Comment: Didn't work for my PDF: couldn't find even a 2-letter word, and when using one letter, the output lost most of the formatting, which should not be touched by a search & replace.