# ghostscript - remove only specific text in PDF file

Tags: pdf, replace, str-replace, ghostscript

Ghostscript allows to generate a new PDF without text from a source one with this easy script:

```
gs -o output_no_text.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFILTERTEXT  input.pdf
```

My purpose is delete just one specific fixed string into the first PDF not all the text. Is there a parameter to set in order to do so?

Comment: Simple answer; no. Its also rather unlikely that could even be made to work in the general case. There are a lot of problems identifying text in PDF files, look at the txtwrite device in Ghostscript to see some of the ways this can be tackled.

Comment: Rather than using gs, a better alternative would be to use pdftk

A detailed solution here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871585/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-a-existing-pdf-file-with-pdftk-or-other-command