# How we can edit and replace text in existing pdf using sed commands, beacaue even after uncompress pdf using pdftk it still not working

Tags: pdftk

[How to find and replace text in a existing PDF file with PDFTK (or other command line application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871585/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-a-existing-pdf-file-with-pdftk-or-other-command/9872494)

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21572046/Can-I-use-sed-to-edit-a-PDF.html

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871585/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-a-existing-pdf-file-with-pdftk-or-other-command

Comment: I have already tried that but it corrupting my pdf and even after using pdftk the broken pdf not getting open