Editing text in a pdf file from Mac Shortcuts App - by running a shell script
I'm trying to automate some forms using the apple shortcuts app and it's built in option to run shell script.  Basically I have a default pdf that I've created for a client that says "dear client", and I want it to automatically change the name of in the pdf to the client's name (which I input at the start of the shortcut).  I'm using homebrew and trying to use packages like pdfgrep, qpdf, and sed.  I also have purchased the mac version of PDFexpert, if I can use some of those commands to more easily edit the files.
I'm doing this on a Macbook Pro M2, and the terminal being used is bash.  I guess I could use zshell but I'm not really sure how to use it.
Here is my shell script so far:
Note that the bolded Client Name represents the variable input from my Apple Shortcuts app.  Not sure exactly what's going on under the hood but it seems to work to find files on my computer.
PDF_FILE="/Users/jonathan/Desktop/Personal Trainer Stuff/Client Documents/Signed Client     Forms/**Client Name**/**Client Name**_WELCOME_FORM.pdf"
OUTPUT_FILE="/Users/jonathan/Desktop/Personal Trainer Stuff/Client Documents/Signed Client Forms/**Client Name**/**Client Name**_WELCOME_FORM.pdf"

echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

qpdf --stream-data=uncompress $1 "$PDF_FILE" --replace-input
sed -i s/("Client")/("**Client Name**")/g "$PDF_FILE"
qpdf --stream-data=compress "$PDF_FILE" $1

I tried this because of what I found on this stackoverflow page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54749404/cant-edit-pdf-file-with-sed-command
but it keeps corrupting my files or giving me errors.  Attached are images of the whole shortcut I've written:
[Script](https://i.sstatic.net/3GI6tK8l.jpg)

How do I do that?  Sounds like a way simpler solution than what I was thinking, no idea that was possible.  I'd like my laptop to be able to fill out client names (and the date while I'm at it), but there's no reason I need to get all fancy with the shell script.

Not sure how to upvote or select your answer, but I read through the pdfcpu guide and was able to make all my forms automate beautifully.  It took a few hours of tinkering but I am really happy with the end product.  Thank you so much!

The core issue here boils down to what is usually called an XY Problem.
The initial focus is on resolving an end issue rather than consider the aim of the task.
The minimal steps here were to edit a PDF template the route can be.

Decompress a working PDF
Use a programmable editor to replace text
Recompress the edited PDF

The Y issue is that will usually corrupt the source PDF, UNLESS it is restructured by including new fonts for the new text, or if very lucky in this flow use:

FIX-QDF to attempt a restructuring using existing embedded fonts.

I proposed an alternate strategy which is simply OVERSTRIKE the template with fresh contents (text or graphics) using a PDF command line programmable editor.
My best suggestion was use PDFCPU which can do the task via API or CLI once you understand its syntax.
